# How to get text between two substrings?

Tags: php

how i can separate text for example

```
$text  = 'TEXT 1: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  TEXT 2:  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'
```

Now if you notice i have TEXT 1:... and TEXT 2:... in variable $text.

How i can limit this text to be showed from TEXT 1 (with str TEXT 1:) to TEXT 2 (without str TEXT 2). And how i can show text just from TEXT 2 to end of text?

Comment: [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) are your friends.

Comment: Did you tried substr http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
print_r(preg_split('/TEXT \d:/', $text, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  
    [1] =>   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to accomplish this,

```
$text  = "TEXT 1: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  TEXT 2:  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

echo substr($text, strpos($text, 'TEXT 1: ') + 8, strpos($text, 'TEXT 2: ') - 8);
```

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/WhirlwindDarkmagentaOctal)

Comment: @Rade if this answer helped, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that will do what you want.

```
$regex = '#TEXT 1: (?<text>.+) TEXT 2#';
$text = "TEXT 1: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  TEXT 2:  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

preg_match($regex, $text, $match);

echo $match['text'];
```

See it in action here https://3v4l.org/VtrZe

Explanation: 
`#` are the delimiters
Then it looks for text 1, and we start a named capture group called `text`
The capture group captures every character, until it hits TEXT 2.
You can access the named capture group with `$match['text']`